# How to set the fixed width and height of a webpage to the maximum width and height of the screen in use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to set a fixed width for my webpage so that users can scroll when they resize their browsers, but I want the maximum size of the page to be the user's maximum screen size (so there are no white spaces if they use a large screen, or so they wouldn't have to scroll immediately if they use a small screen).

I tried using Javascript to create functions that returns the screen width and height, but it seems that it isn't possible to call these functions as the width and height of the page.

What I have right now:

```
<script>
    function getScreenWidth() {
        return screen.width;
    }
    function getScreenHeight() {
        return screen.height;
    }
 </script>

 <body width="getScreenWidth()">
  ...
 </body>
```

Calling the getScreenWidth() function into the width of the body doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you're trying to do. Is there a reason that setting `height: 100%; width: 100%` in CSS won't work for you?

Comment: Yeah, what Rory said. If that doesn't work, you could always specify: `body{ width:100vw; height:100vh; }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use css properties in new browsers and the units `vh` and `vw` which are viewport height and width. Thus you can use something like

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

where we include the `min-{width,height}` attributes for legacy browsers which do not support `vw, vh`. If you do not want the use to be able to scroll you could also include `overflow: hidden` as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I was unaware about `width:100vw` option but that is good since that is only CSS.

```
<script>
    function setWH() {
        $('body').css('width': $( window ).width() + 'px');
        $('body').css('height': $( window ).height() + 'px');
    }
 </script>

 <body onload="setWH()">
  ...
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viewport Units to set sizes relative to the viewport width and height. So, for example, "max-width:100vw;" sets an element's maximum width to the width of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

> Fennec 1.1 (Firefox for mobile) also adds support for `minimum-scale`, `maximum-scale`, and
>   `user-scalable`, with defaults and limits similar to Safari's. These
>   properties affect the `initial scale` and `width`, as well as limiting
>   changes in zoom level.

Just to clarify things even more, in iPhone and iPad devices, the device-width always corresponds to the width of the device in portrait mode, regardless of whether the device is in that mode or landscape instead. With other devices, its device-width changes depending on its orientation.

> Further you can control the rendering using CSS media queries for
>   different devices. Lets see some more `CSS media queries` now that
>   capture different devices and screen dimensions:

```
/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### iPhone 4+ Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### iPhone 5 Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media (device-height: 568px) and (device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### iPhone 6 and 6 plus Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media (min-device-height: 667px) and (min-device-width: 375px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Tablets Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
  /* some CSS here */
}

/* #### Desktops #### */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  /* some CSS here */
}
```